# Getting more than 100% accuracy for model.evaluate() for CNN, when I run the model multiple times. How do I separate each model.fit() instance?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am currently trying to run a CNN model that looks at images of cats and dogs to try to classify them (an old kaggle question). However, I want to see what the effects of running different numbers of epochs is on model accuracy.

Unfortunately, when I run model.fit() multiple times, alongside a model.evaluate(), the accuracy scores seems to be adding on top of one another from the previous model run. For example the INCORRECT output I get is:

```
100 Epochs Test Accuracy: 67.7%
200 Epochs Test Accuracy: 98.5%
300 Epochs Test Accuracy: 259.0%
```

My CNN is build as such:

```
input_layer = Input(shape=(img_shape, img_shape, 3))

convolution_layer_1 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(5,5), activation = 'relu')(input_layer)
max_pool_1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=2)(convolution_layer_1)

convolution_layer_2 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(5,5), activation = 'relu')(max_pool_1)
max_pool_2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=2)(convolution_layer_2)

dense_layer_1 = Dense(32, activation='relu')(max_pool_2)
flatten_layer_1 = Flatten()(dense_layer_1)
dropout_1 = Dropout(0.4)(flatten_layer_1)

output_layer = Dense(1, activation='softmax')(dropout_1)

model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Then I ran the following series of model.fit() and model.evaluate() commands, with only the epochs value (and print statements) being changed each time.

```
model.fit_generator(
    training_set_data, 
    epochs = 100, 
    validation_data = test_set_data, 
)

score_100 = model.evaluate(test_set_data)
print('\nTest accuracy for 100 epochs: %0.4f%%' % (score_100[0] * 100))

# 100 Epochs Test Accuracy: 67.7%

-------------------------------------------

model.fit_generator(
    training_set_data, 
    epochs = 200, 
    validation_data = test_set_data, 
)

score_200 = model.evaluate(test_set_data)
print('\nTest accuracy for 200 epochs: %0.4f%%' % (score_200[0] * 100))

#200 Epochs Test Accuracy: 98.5%

-------------------------------------------

model.fit_generator(
    training_set_data, 
    epochs = 300, 
    validation_data = test_set_data, 
)

score_300 = model.evaluate(test_set_data)
print('\nTest accuracy for 300 epochs: %0.4f%%' % (score_300[0] * 100))

#300 Epochs Test Accuracy: 259.0%
```

How do I run these three epochs iterations of the model.fit() separately? Such that the output of the model.evaluate() is printed correctly? For example:

```
100 Epochs Test Accuracy: 67.7%
200 Epochs Test Accuracy: 70.5%
300 Epochs Test Accuracy: 74.0%
```

I tried creating 3 separate compilations of the CNN to run each individually, as such:

```
model1 = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
model1.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model2 = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
model2.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

then

```
model1.fit ....etc
model2.fit ....etc
```

However now the problem seems to be with the model itself? Because if I run model3 directly (for 300 epochs) without running model1 and model2, I still get an accuracy score of 200+%

What's going on!?

Comment: You're using `fit_generator()`, not `fit()`. You'll probably need to iterate over the `fit_generator()` for it to do things.

Comment: @AKX I tried changing them all to ```fit``` but the issue remains

Comment: Can you try swtiching from `softmax` to `sigmoid` for the outputs? See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/62844619/826983

Comment: @StefanFalk changing to ```sigmoid``` also did not resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what the problem is in your case but your code, with some minor modifications, trains a model to recognize wether an image is `IS_NUMBER` or not.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow import keras


(ds_train, ds_test), ds_info = tfds.load(
    'mnist',
    split=['train', 'test'],
    shuffle_files=True,
    as_supervised=True,
    with_info=True,
)

inputs_spec, outputs_spec = ds_train.element_spec

input_layer = layers.Input(shape=inputs_spec.shape)
x = input_layer

x = layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3))(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=2)(x)

x = layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3))(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=2)(x)

x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Dense(32)(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.1)(x)

x = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=x)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

IS_NUMBER = 3

def is_number(inp, tar):
  return inp, tf.cast(tf.equal(tar, IS_NUMBER), dtype=tf.int32)

ds_train = ds_train.map(is_number).repeat()

train = ds_train.padded_batch(50)

model.fit(
    train, 
    steps_per_epoch=200, 
    epochs=5,
    class_weight={0: 0.9, 1: 0.1}
)
```

I get similar results using:

```py
# ...

x = layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=x)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'

IS_NUMBER = 3

def is_number(inp, tar):
  return inp, tf.cast(tf.equal(tar, IS_NUMBER), dtype=tf.int32)

# ...

model.fit(
    train, 
    steps_per_epoch=200, 
    epochs=5
)
```

Maybe this helps you figuring out the issue with your own code/data.

Comment: Thanks @StefanFalk, but im quite new to all this. What's the impact of recognizing whether a an image is ```IS_NUMBER``` or not? Also what does the ```def is_number``` function and ```ds_train.padded_batch()``` do?

Comment: I needed a dataset for my example and MNIST was my choice. I only did this s.t. we can train a simple binary-classifier as in your case. `is_number()` only converts the target from a value in 0-9 to 0 or 1 (binary). `padded_batch()`, as the name suggests, creates a padded batch. Since all inputs are the same, there will be no padding - we only need the batching here. Usually it's a good idea to use larger batch-sizes (see stochastic gradient descent).

Comment: I'm trying your ```is_number``` suggestion now, but since I loaded the data from a directory using ```tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator```, I get the error ```'DirectoryIterator' object has no attribute 'map'```. I tried to resolve this by doing: ```training_set_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    training_set_data.map(is_number).repeat())``` but it still shows the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: It appears to me that you lack some fundamental basics here. `ImageDataGenerator` appears not to be a `tf.data.Dataset` the error tells you that your object has no `map()` function. Maybe start from scratch and only take small steps. First, try to create a `tf.data.Dataset` that will yield one example at a time. Inspect each example and make sure they look correctly (debug it or write a test). After validating that your data is correct, create a _simple_ model. Boil it down to the essentials and then start a training on a _batched_ dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to the wrong parameter score_300[0] will give you the loss value for the evaluation data set and score_300[1] will give you the accuracy value in all the three cases you have referred the wrong value score_100, score_200 and score_300

Comment: Yes, I actually managed to catch that error later on. So my actual accuracy scores were flat at 50%...and errors were the one balloning to 200+%

I still also do not know why the accuracy remained at 50%. Perhaps because the number of images in the dataset was really low.

Comment: that is a loss that is 0.2 odd and it is not measured in percentage, my friend.

Comment: use sequential model add more dense layer and Conv layers and try data augmentation as the sample size is very less and do some RND with batch normalization and other things and you might end up in getting more accuracy.

Comment: refer this link for data augmentation and others https://www.kaggle.com/ashokkumar071994/celebfaces